# Choosing between Gaussian/Laplacian prior distributions for MCMC regression

Tags: regression, markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, laplace-distribution

When doing a linear regression using MCMC, you have to specify prior distributions for the values of the regression coefficients of the independent variables. If all of the priors are Gaussian distributions with mean 0 and the same standard deviation, then the MCMC technique gives the same result as a Ridge regression, and if the priors are Laplace distributions with mean 0 and identical standard deviations, it is the same as a Lasso regression. However, when using MCMC, you have the option to mix up the priors, using Gaussian or Laplace distributions with nonzero means and different standard deviations.

My question is about how to choose between Gaussian and Laplacian. Since Laplace distributions have fatter tails than Gaussian distributions, my intuition says that I should use Laplacian priors with high standard deviations for variables whose regression coefficients are highly uncertain.

On the other hand, Lasso regressions tend to force regression coefficients to zero, so I intuitively expect similar behavior when using Laplacians in MCMC, which leads me to think that Gaussian distributions are better for highly uncertain variables. The Lasso behavior is explained in https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat508/lesson/5/5.4 but I'm not sure if the reasoning about diamond shapes holds for MCMC regression.

In general, when using MCMC, what is a good heuristic or process to decide which type of distribution to use as priors?

Comment: The choice of priors has nothing to do with MCMC and vice-versa. Priors are chosen for either subjective or objective reasons but not for convenience in running an MCMC algorithm...

Comment: There are more choices to make when running MCMC and the outcomes are more complex to understand. In any case, would you be able to share those reasons?